# Debugging errors in user app. It is possible?

Tags: java, android

I have a question, is it possible to write and read the user logs ( user from internal tests app) from run debugging on the app phone to detect what error might have happened?

Comment: You can use crash report platforms like Firebase crashlytics or Instabug

Answer (score 0):

YESSSSS, firebase crashlytics for in depth details on ur preferred logs, works exactly like normal debug . or google play console to monitor crashes,ANRs and much more.

Comment: What you mentioned only works for crash, I don't see the option to log everything.

Comment: oh in that case firebase analytics (https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?platform=android)